# Groovy Sql to fetch all columns

Tags: sql, groovy, sap-ase

I am using Groovy Sql to fetch results. This is the output from my Linux box.

```
%isql -U abc -P abc -S support
1> sp_configure 'number of open partitions'
2> go
 Parameter Name                 Default     Memory Used Config Value    Run Value    Unit                 Type
 ------------------------------ ----------- ----------- ------------  ------------ -------------------- ----------
 number of open partitions              500        5201         5000          5000 number               dynamic

(1 row affected)
(return status = 0)
1>
```

I am using groovy code

```
def sql = Sql.newInstance("jdbc:abc:sybase://harley:6011;DatabaseName=support;",dbuname,dbpassword,Driver)
sql.eachRow("sp_configure 'number of open partitions'"){ row ->
        println row.run_value
    }
```

but it gives me

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: [abc][Sybase JDBC Driver]Invalid column name: run_value
```

So it says it cannot get the speciied columns, is there a way it can fetch the result and display?

**Update**

I used the below code

```
sql.eachRow("sp_configure 'number of open partitions'"){ row ->
            println row
    }
```

and it gives me

```
[Parameter Name:number of open partitions     , Default:        500, Memory Used:       5201, Config Value:        5000, Run Value:        5000, Unit:number              , Type:dynamic   ]
```

How can I get `Run Value`? (since it has a space in it)

`row.Run Value` will not work for sure

Comment: Does `println row.Type` work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this work?  Querying the meta-data for the column name and getting the value by index:

```
sql.eachRow("sp_configure 'number of open partitions'"){ row ->
  (1..row.getMetaData().columnCount).each {
    println "${row.metaData().getColumnName( it )} = ${row[ it ]}"
  }
}
```

Or, to get the column directly

```
row.'Run Value'
```

Comment: it gives me `Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: [informatica][SQLServer JDBC Driver]Invalid column name: metaData` exception

Comment: Please see my update, how to get column names having space in it?

Comment: @AbhishekSimon updated my answer to fix the `metaData` problem, and add this as an answer :-)  Good luck!

Comment: tim_yates, your suggestion gives invalid column index (SQLException) because of the code ${row[it]} as the last value of the loop will be out of bounds. Also , it prints wrong data against each column Correct code would be println "${row.metaData().getColumnName( it )} = ${row[ (it-1) ]}"

Answer (score 2):

Additioannly to @tim_yates's answer I'd like to note that `row` has `toRowResult()` method. It allows to get a row simply as a Map. No need to call `getMetadata()` if we need only column names or table width.

```
sql.eachRow("sp_configure 'number of open partitions'"){ row ->
  row.toRowResult().each(){ colName, value ->
    println "${colName} = ${value}"
  }
}
```

This code doing absolutely the same but looks much more clear

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is getAt(int). In your case, this will return the 'Run Value':

`row.getAt(-3)`